# Find Image Class and Append the Source of it using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have many images tags that looks like below

```
<img class="vCSS_img_alternate_product_photo" id="alternate_product_photo_6" style="border-color:#666666;" src="/v/vspfiles/photos/ChiWahGuitar-6S.jpg" border="1" onmouseover='javascript:change_product_photo(6);return false;'>
```

Using Jquery what i want to do is find all Source (SRC tag ) whose class name is **vCSS_img_alternate_product_photo** and append the SRC with http://www.mydomain.com

So in above example the image src would be http://www.mydomain.com/v/vspfiles/photos/ChiWahGuitar-6S.jpg

Or it would be

```
<img class="vCSS_img_alternate_product_photo" id="alternate_product_photo_6" style="border-color:#666666;" src="http://www.mydomain.com/v/vspfiles/photos/ChiWahGuitar-6S.jpg" border="1" onmouseover='javascript:change_product_photo(6);return false;'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
$('.vCSS_img_alternate_product_photo').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.mydomain.com' + $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".vCSS_img_alternate_product_photo").each(function(){
        var current_src = $(this).attr("src");
        var new_src = "http://www.mydomain.com/"+current_src;

        $(this).attr("src",new_src);
    });
})
```